# /var/log/squid/access.log is empty when I use proxy from remote computers

Tags: ubuntu, squid, nat, logging

I have configured squid to work as NAT using

```
apt-get install squid
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

Have added to /etc/squid/squid.conf

```
acl internal_network src 192.168.0.0/24
http_access allow internal_network

access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
```

**Problem: /var/log/squid/access.log is empty when I use proxy from remote computers.**
When I make `telnet localhost 3128` then it does write to log:
`1308144959.810      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_DENIED/400 1693 NONE NONE:// - NONE/- text/html`
So the problem is that logging is somehow turned off for remote proxy use.

Permissions:

- /var/log/squid/ - 0777
- /var/log/squid/* - 0666

`cat /var/log/squid/cache.log | grep access`
gives
`logfileOpen: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log`

without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My network interface was br0, not eth0 or eth1

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:3128`

fixed the problem.